# How to deploy .NET Core 3.1. app with only special locales

Tags: .net-core, deployment, localization

I'm deploying a .NET Core app which relies on a few dependent packages. These bring multiple locales with them (i.e. creating language folders in deployment folder). The same happens if I deploy as Self-contained deployments (SCD) for a few .NET libraries. I only want English or one select other language, as the app itself is also English only. Is there a way to set this, so that only en is deployed?